# Signature schemes that prevent extracting public key

Tags: signing

Are there any signature schemes in Substrate that prevent recovering/extracting the public key from a signature?

Answer (score 1):

It appears using [SR21559](https://doc.deepernetwork.org/v3/advanced/cryptography/#sr25519) has the desired property:

> One sacrifice that is made when using Schnorr signatures over ECDSA is that both require 64 bytes, but only ECDSA signatures communicate their public key.

Obviously, in other contexts, this is not a sacrifice but a benefit.